# How to read MS Access Date/Time field from Python

Tags: python, ms-access

I am reading .mdb file (MS Access) from Python using pyodbc.
There is a column in the table with double-precision data type  which is used to store date/time.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/210604

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/210276

How I can convert this double-precision value to format "mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss" ?
  In many databases there is an SQL function which does it.
  In MS Access there is Format() function, but I think it is not possible to use it in SQL - may be I am wrong here?
May be exists the python function which does this conversion?

Comment: If `SELECT yourField ...` is returning a numeric value then try `SELECT CDate(yourField) ...`

Comment: [`Format`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-Function-6F29D87B-8761-408D-81D3-63B9CD842530#bmexamples) should work. If not, cast it's contents: `Format(CDate(yourField),...)`